# C3JS not correctly binding y2 axis json data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, c3.js

I have a graph that is a time series with two y axes. The left y axis shows latency in milliseconds and the right y axis (y2) shows throughput. However, it appears the json data isnt being correctly binded to y2 as its acting as if no data was presented to it. 
This is a small subset of the json I'm working with:

```
 json: [{
        latency: 59,
        datestamp: "20160712",
        throughput: 46
      }, {
        latency: 272,
        datestamp: "20160713",
        throughput: 30
      }]
```

Also note that I overrode the axes as stated in the [documentation](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-data-axes)

```
axes: {
  'latency': 'y',
  'throughput': 'y2'
}
```

Here is the JS fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz8nx8dc/3/

As you can see the throughput has much higher values than 1.0 yet y2 tick values arent being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lz8nx8dc/5/

The solution was to move axes to be a property of data:

```
data: {
    axes: {
      'latency': 'y',
      'throughput': 'y2'
    }
}
```